# I Can't Run Docker Microservice on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I'm facing a problem with my microservice running on Visual Studio 2019 with Docker.  It works fine with IIS though, but it stops after starting running when I use Docker (I am using Visual Studio 2019).

CODE:
Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest
RUN mkdir app

#Install debugger
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | bash /dev/stdin -v latest -l /vsdbg

EXPOSE 32773
EXPOSE 32774
EXPOSE 80

#Keep the debugger container on
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

docker.compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  identity_hope.api:
    image: identity_hope.api
    environment:
      - ConnectionString=Server=myIP,1433;User=sa;Password=myPassword;Database=myDb;
    build:
      context: ./../mycroservice/services/identity/identity
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "32773:80"
      - "32774:80"
    volumes:
      - ./../mycroservice/services/identity/identity/bin/pub/:/app
    container_name: identity_hope.api
```

launchSettings.json

```
"Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/weatherforecast",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:32773;http://+:32774"
      },
      "useSSL": true
    }
```

Console Results (port is Up and OK) - See link: 
https://gyazo.com/a9778fe3fda779787d163074d49beb4e

What is wrong with it?
thanks in advance for you support.

Comment: Which error did you get, what is the problem with files above?

Comment: I don't get any error, the VS just stop running after few seconds, but if I run on IIS it works perfectly fine.